# Как устроена модель делегирования событий?

Tags: java, события

Когда-то извещение о событии распространялось по всей иерархии компонентов. Все компоненты получали извещения, которые могли и не обрабатывать. На смену этой модели пришла **модель делегирования событий**.

Как устроена **модель делегирования событий**?

Comment: Это в какой-то книге написано?

Comment: @MikhailVaysman [стр 856](https://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/31249554/)

Answer (score 2):

Модель делегирования событий состоит из **приемника** и **источника**. Источник генерирует событие и извещает о нем один или несколько приемников. Приемнику надлежит просто ждать извещение, а по получении обработать и вернуть управление.

В данной модели источник обязательно **регистрирует** приемник(и), чтобы последний(ие) мог(ли) получить извещение о событии.

Comment: Можете ещё добавить, что есть стандартные классы для создания своих источников и приемников - Observer и Observable.